# Replacing "true"/"false" with images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gsub

I have a table in Rails where a number of columns are full of true/false values.

How can I do a performant substitution, replacing a table full of `true`s and `false`s with small images to represent true and false?

Comment: By "table" do you mean an HTML table? If so, a jQuery selector and `.each()` should cover this. (I can post a real answer with some code if this is what you meant.)

Comment: @Hans - that's exactly it. The table is being dynamically generated so javascript could be perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would usually add a class to a `<span>` or `<div>` element, and then use CSS selectors to apply the appropriate background image for each case.

In the view...

```
<span class='foo-indicator <%= @item.foo? ? 'foo' : 'not-foo' %>'>&nbsp;</span>
```

In the CSS stylesheet...

```
.foo-indicator {
  /* Specify height, width, positioning, etc. */
}
.foo {
  background-image: url('../images/is-foo.png')
}
.not-foo {
  background-image: url('../images/not-foo.png')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a helper method, something like this, in your application helper

```
def display_status(status)
  (status == true) ? image("true.png") : image("false.png") 
end

private
def image(name)
 "/images/#{name}"
end
```

And when you are creating the table, call the 'display_status' method with the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

the same idea as Steve Jorgensen but without css

`<img src="<%= @item.foo? ? "/images/true.png" : "/images/false.png" %>"></img>`